# How can I fetch data from a php/html form into database?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have problems when trying to update my database with the data posted in my web system. I've created a php file that contains the html forms as far as my order-form is concerned, where I can select several producs and their quantity. Then I've created this :

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <?php 
        require_once("buzzcafe_fns.php");
     do_html_header('Order form');
    db_connect();
        $otable=$_POST['otable'];
        $title=$_POST['title'];
        $quantity=$_POST['quantity'];
        $datetime=$_SESSION['datetime'];
        $username=$_SESSION['username'];

        if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
                {
                        if( !$otable || !$title || !$quantity )
                        {
                            echo'<font color="red">Please fill in all required fields</font>';
                            exit;
                        }
                }
            $insertOrder = mysql_query('INSERT INTO orders VALUES($oid, $title, $quantity, $sum, $datetime, $username)')or die(mysql_error());

                        echo ('<p>Your order is added</p>');
                        echo ('<p>View your order <a href="vieworder.php?insertOrder='.$insertOrder.'"></a></p>');
                        echo ('<p>Add a new order <a href="addorder-form.php"></a></p>');
                        echo ('<p>Return in main page<a href="members.php"></a></p>');

?>
```

What is wrong on this code ?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: When I compile this (with phpMyadmin, wampserver) it responds: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'db_connect' (T_STRING) in C:\wamp\www\addorder.php on line 9.

Comment: @JaneDimi Did you include `session_start();` anywhere? Since you are using sessions, I did not see it posted in your code, nor any mention of it. Since the error starts at line 9, which is your session starting. And/or could be your date/time format if `$datetime=$_SESSION['datetime'];` is in fact line 9.

Comment: You are also wide open to SQL injections, using an obsolete MySQL API, and are producing invalid HTML.

Comment: yes, you're right as far as session_start() is concerned, I'm dealing with it now. The problem is that I don't know how to set my variables properly.In the addorder-form.php where is my code in html I use only a query in database where I select the title of my products. In the addorder.php I want to have features like title, quantity, otable(id key for the tables of the cafeteria),datetime and the shop assistant's username. How I declare them? Which of them is "post"?

Comment: @JaneDimi Then it seems that the problem could also be inside `buzzcafe_fns.php` - is that your connection file?

Comment: @Fred-ii- this file contains all the files containing my functions. Like a library. My code as far as connection to db is the following: function db_connect() {
$db_info["host"] = "localhost";
$db_info["username"] = "root";
$db_info["password"] = "";
$db_info["database"] = "buzzcafe";
if (!($db = mysql_connect($db_info["host"], $db_info["username"], $db_info["password"]))) 
{ echo 'Database connect error'; }
mysql_query ('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
mysql_query ('SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=utf8_unicode_ci');
if (!(mysql_select_db($db_info["database"], $db))) { echo 'Database select error'; }

Comment: @JaneDimi As John Conde stated about invalid HTML, one example is this `echo ('<p>Return in main page<a href="members.php"></a></p>');` which has no text to show the link itself, which should read as `echo ('<p><a href="members.php">Return in main page</a></p>');`

Comment: @JaneDimi Please don't paste code like that in a comment, place it in your question instead with a reference to it. It's very hard to read.

Comment: @JaneDimi For one thing, you have a missing closing brace `}` for `function db_connect() {` in what you showed me in your comment code. Try adding another `}` after your last brace, after `echo 'Database select error'; }`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm really sorry. That won't happen again :/

Comment: The missing closing brace } was a copy/paste fault.

Comment: @JaneDimi This line doesn't seem right to me with the `!` placed like that `if (!(mysql_select_db($db_info["database"], $db))) {` **try** `if ((!mysql_select_db($db_info["database"], $db))) {` having `!` before `mysql_select_db`

Comment: @JaneDimi And also in `if (!($db = mysql_connect($db_info["host"],` not sure about that. Try `if ((!$db = mysql_connect($db_info["host"],` can't be 100% sure though.

Comment: @JaneDimi How are you calling your `do_html_header` function?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I tried your suggestion but then I have errors while compling. Well, I'm sure that this part of code I've sent you is working well since in other sql_queries I've operated in other files I had right results.

Comment: @JaneDimi I can't wrap my head around your DB connection function. You should try setting it up in a more simple manner. I don't know what else to tell you that could help any further.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I run my code again (FYI I changed place of the function db_connect and put it just before the query of insert into) and now I have this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$otable' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\wamp\www\addorder.php on line 11

Answer (score 0):

This statement, which infact is the core, is incorrect

```
$insertOrder = mysql_query('INSERT INTO orders VALUES($oid, $title, $quantity, $sum, $datetime, $username)')or die(mysql_error());
```

It should be

```
$insertOrder = mysql_query("INSERT INTO orders VALUES($oid, $title, $quantity, $sum, $datetime, $username)")or die(mysql_error());
```